# Can Apache Ace be used as Maven repository?

Tags: java, apache, maven, repository, apache-ace

we want to use some repository for maven, we have used Artifactory, Nexus etc as repository. **

> But I just want to know whether we can use Apache Ace as Maven
>   repository?

** 
If yes, how to configure ace in Maven's setting.xml for repository?
Please advise..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but Nexus as well as Artifactory support p2 repositories which can be used for Eclipse as source of plugins but for that you need the commercial ones. Furthermore i'm not sure if Apache Ace is going into the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ACE currently comes with a repository that supports the OBR (OSGi Bundle Repository) specification. That means it contains artifacts that can all be referenced directly via a URL and these artifacts contain metadata that is described in a file called "repository.xml". The format is not the same as Maven, so unless Maven starts supporting OBR, the answer right now is "no".